# Can people find and download the Code File linked to your aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I imported this aspx page done by a former dev who worked for the company I'm in now. I found that the aspx page left by him doesn't have a codebehind file so I assumed this wasn't the source code. I can't find the source so I added a code file and try to work it out on my own. But my main concern is this: clients can't access the code behind, right? Is a manually added code file subject to the same protection?

Comment: Code could be inside dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codebehind file is there as a place to put your server side code. However it's technically not necessary to have one since you can put the code in the aspx file using c# script tags. It's however recommended to put it in the codebehind file for better separation between markup and code.
It does not matter if you add it yourself or if Visual Studio adds it for you. It does not change anything in terms of access. In all events it executes on the server.

Comment: Oh ok, glad to know my code's safe. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

If your server is properly configured to run ASP.NET applications - which I believe it is - then IIS will not serve .cs files to a client. These will normally be accessible only through FTP. Try it yourself, by browsing to any `.cs` file in your application :)

Also notice that what you get when you browse to an .aspx file is not the very same code you'd see in Visual Studio, but the result of that being processed. IIS will serve the resulting HTML. So even if you have server side code in the ASPX file, that won't be visible to an end user browsing through your application.

Comment: Thanks Renan. I did what you said to try browsing for the .cs file from another PC and I keep getting a 404.7 error. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a web application project; in this case, the code is in the code-behind file as @TGH mentioned, and the code would be in the DLL compiled for the web application.  Therefore, the only way to get that code is use a tool like Telerik JustDecompile, and decompile that DLL to grab the source code for EVERY file in the project.  It would be much better to have the source, as these decompile tools do not include everything in that code-behind file.

Comment: Yeah, I'd really be much better to have the source since I'll be needing to add a few modifications with this work.